# Login view / logged view and segues: what is the correct workflow to adopt?

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, segue

The problem is very simple. My app has a logged view (actually more than one) and a login view, on login a `Show Detail` segue is followed to the logged view.

On logged out I was thinking just to call `popToViewController` but then I remember than my app will preserve its login state, so I may be in a case where the user logs out and there is just the logged view instantiated in the app and nothing to pop to.

Now I have another `Show` segue from the logged view to the login view. But I'm wondering if this is the correct action to take.

What is the correct workflow to adopt?

Comment: Personally, I like to maintain 2 different storyboards for login related view controllers, and the logged in view controllers. In `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, check if the user is logged in. Then use `instantiateViewController:` on the storyboard of your choice, and set the `rootViewController` of your app window with this instance. It's that simple. Assumption here is, you have some mechanism here to check the logged-in status of the user.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what @n00bProgrammer mentioned in the comments. I think it's good practice to keep the `Login` and the `Main` interface (call them what you want) seperate.

You can do this, by changing the `rootViewController` property on your application's main `UIWindow` object. You can access this through the property `window` of your `AppDelegate`.

The code to assign a new `rootViewController` to your application could look like this:

```
// Change the root view controller of the application window to the main storyboard
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
UITabBarController *mainTabBarController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTabBarController"];

UIWindow *mainApplicationWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
mainApplicationWindow.rootViewController = mainTabBarController;
```

Whenever the user gets logged out, you can change the `rootViewController` back to the one that you showed on login:

```
// Switch back to the login view
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Login" bundle: nil];
UINavigationController *rootNavigationController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RootNavigationController"];

UIWindow *mainApplicationWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
mainApplicationWindow.rootViewController = rootNavigationController;
```